# What happens when one declares more signals(variables) than needed in the sensitivity list in Verilog or VHDL

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

It has been a while since I have used VHDL and Verilog and while studying some material I came up with this question.Unfortunately I do not any specific example or issue.

Comment: FYI, Verilog has auto-sensitivity with `always @*` (or the synonymous `always @(*)`) for combinational logic. SystemVerilog has `always_comb`. Not sure if VHLD has an equivalent.

Comment: I think in the synthesis, the unnecessary signals will be removed.

Comment: The only times I've ever used anything other than `always @*` or `always @(clk, rst) <insert edges>` is in behavioral code where I'm modeling some analog component. My rule of thumb is, if it's not a clk or reset, it shouldn't be in the sensitivity list if it's being synthesized. I have only ever seen problems when people list the signals in the sensitivity list, and they are usually a pita to debug.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can only specify signals in a sensitivity list and no variables.

**For synthesis:**
There is usually no difference, because synthesis doesn't rely on sensitivity lists.

**For simulation:**
If you specify to few signals, you might not see the expected behavior. If you specify to much signals, you might see a behavior that does not match the synthesis behavior.

In addition, by specifying more signals than required, the simulation loop will be slower due to more possible events that must be checked.

Comment: Synthesis does care about the sensitivity list for sequential logic. Typically the first signal is treated as the clock and the other signals need to be asynchronous reset/preset. For combinational logic, I agree with you.

Comment: No that's not true. Sequential code is mostly generated base on read signals. You can have an arbitrary order of signals. And you can use more than one clock per process. The PoC Library contains code as a prove for the latter statement. Moreover it's the recommended style for describing dual port RAMs as proposed by IEEE 1076.4 (withdrawn).

Comment: "...by specifying more signals than required, the simulation loop will be slower..." Likely more significant than traversing an incrementally expanded sensitivity set (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2) would be needlessly executing a processes sequence of statements, particularly those processes containing purely combinational logic (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) 6.4) and especially dataflow descriptions where conditional evaluation is minimized and expression signal evaluation is maximized.

Comment: Clarification: my comment on sequential logic was based on Verilog (IEEE 1364) and SystemVerilog (IEEE 1800). I rarely work with VHDL (IEEE 1076) which has a different set of rules and behavior. My original comment is still valid in relation to Verilog.

Comment: "If you specify to much signals, you might see a behavior that does not match the synthesis behavior." Is there an example of this (for a synthesizable logic)? I can only imagine examples like counting activations of a process etc that aren't synthesizable to begin with. What functional harm could possibly occur from an activation of process with an event that has no significance to that process?

Answer (score 1):

For sequential logic, Design Compiler produces an error if a redundant signal in the sensitivity list is not suitable to be a reset or clock signal. Multiple reset signals are permitted, but there is no permission for multiple clocks.

Let's think that is what we intend to design.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
    if (rst)
        a <= 1'b0;
    else if (en)
        a <= b:
```

If we add `en`, `a`, `b`, or `c` to the sensitivity list, the error message below is produced.

> The expression in the reset condition of the 'if' statement in this
>   'always' block can only be a simple identifier or its negation.
>   (ELAB-303)

This is the code causing the error (`en` is the uninvited signal).

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst, posedge en)
    if (rst)
        a <= 1'b0;
    else if (en)
        a <= b;
```

The `en` signal is not suitable to be a reset, because it doesn't set `a` to a constant value.

In the code below, the redundant signal is `c`. It's not used inside the `always` block, so can't be a reset. Then it becomes a candidate for clock, but we have `clk` signal too. The same error message is produced here.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst, posedge c)
    if (rst)
        a <= 1'b0;
    else if (en)
        a <= b;
```

The code snippet below is synthesizable. Since `c` sets `a` signal to a constant value, it can be a reset as well as `rst` signal. DC will synthesize it, but the combinational logic on the reset path may cause timing violations.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst, posedge c)
    if (rst)
        a <= 1'b0;
    else if (c)
        a <= 1'b1;
    else if (en)
        a <= b;
```

My last example has a redundant signal in the sensitivity list w/o any trigger condition (pos/negedge). DC produces a different error here.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge rst, c)
    if (rst)
        a <= 1'b0;
    else if (c)
        a <= 1'b1;
    else if (en)
        a <= b;
```

> The event depends on both edge and nonedge expressions, which
>   synthesis does not support. (ELAB-91)

All these cases can be extended, but the results are not guaranteed to be the same with the other synthesis tools.

Answer (score 0):

We always use always block with clock and reset in sensitivity list to describe sequence circuit.And use always block with every driver signals in sensitivity list to describe combinational circuit.

Sometimes sensitivity list is only important for simulations but if you forget a signal in sensitivity list you may get the wrong simulations. In real FPGA function will work fine if your logic is correct.

But it can cause some problem.

For example, if you describe a function like `a=b&c` in an always block with sensitivity (b); But you forget `c`. Then in your simulation `a` will not change when `c` is changed. But the circuit in real FPGA, will be the correct description of the function `a=b&c`. And you may get a warning when you synthesize your code.

You can call it ‘pre-sim and post-sim inconsistent’.

The real scary thing is that your pre-sim is right but your post-sim is wrong. That may cause the FPGA to infer incorrect logic.

[fpga](/questions/tagged/fpga) [verilog](/questions/tagged/verilog)  [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl)